# Polymer - Refresh Template With Bound Data

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

**How do I refresh bound data in the `order-items-list` element from the `post-card` element?**

I'm using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) (the `polymer-element`s are in the shadow DOM).

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but to no avail (I'm new to web development). One of the thing I tried is this: (givers error: `Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined`)

```
this.$.orderitemstemplateparent.getElementsByTagName('template')[0].iterator_.updateIteratedValue();
```

I have the following 3 files:

`index.html`:

```
<html>
    <body unresolved>
        <core-header-panel>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="order-items-div>
                    <order-items-list id="order-items-list">
```

`order-items-list.html`:

```
<polymer-element name="order-items-list">
    <template>
        <div id="orderitemstemplateparent">
            <template id="order-items-template" repeat="{{post in posts}}>
    <script>
        Polymer ({
            // FUNCTIONS THAT UPDATE THE DATA {{posts}} HERE 
        });
    </script>
```

`post-card.html`:

```
<polymer-element name="post-card">
    <template id="card-template">
        <div id="card-header">
            <paper-ripple on-tap="{{cardClick}}"></paper-ripple>
    <script>
        Polymer ({
            cardClick: function(event, detail, sender) {
                // RELOAD #order-items-template FROM HERE
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you have properties with a `-` in the key, you need to use bracket notation to access them.

```
this.$['order-items-template-parent'].getElementsByTagName('template')[0].iterator_.updateIteratedValue();
```

Otherwise, it's parsed like this:

```
this.$.order - items - template - parent.getElementsByTagName('template')[0].iterator_.updateIteratedValue();
```

You're doing some weird subtraction, and `parent` is undefined.

Comment: In the actual code the ID did not have a `-` (sorry about that). I only added this when rewriting the code for the question. Thanks for the answer though. I updated the question and inserted the brackets.

Comment: You're still doing it wrong - you need the quotes, and no period at the beginning.

Comment: Now I updated the question to be closer to my actual code. I removed `-`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to update the whole set by clicking inside one of its elements. Im not sure I understand the user case but how about firing an event that the list element can subscribe to and react updating everything?

Comment: @sesteva No, I want to click on an element of one set and refresh another set. Basically there is a list of items and when I click on one of them, it will be added to a list on a server. I then want to refresh another list which will get the list of added items from the server.

Comment: You can still fire an event on one element, pass the model and get the information on whoever subscribed to that event